# Invoke and control GDB from Python

Tags: python, gdb

I am running a Python GUI application. I want to invoke and control GDB from it, like load an executable file, set breakpoints etc. I see that GDB has a command line interface which can be used by sending strings to the GDB process, but I want to do it the Python way. Is there a `gdb.py`? I see that "archer" branch has something like "import gdb", but it doesn't work in Ubuntu's default installation of Python. Where do I get this module or is there any other method to control GDB from Python?

Comment: A how to do the ABC question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060565/how-to-script-gdb-with-python-example-add-breakpoints-run-what-breakpoint-d

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can control GDB from Python. The Python documentation is at http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python.

If you want an example of some scripting, take a look at http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548

Comment: thx. i've mentioned this archer branch in my question already. it seems to be a work-in-progress. i'm going to give it a shot. but what i actually want is a python module that hooks up with existing GDB, not the archer one.

Answer (score 9):

[pygdbmi](http://grassfedcode.com/pygdbmi/) is what you want.

With it I was able to reset an embedded target from Python using the following:

```
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController
if __name__ == '__main__':
    gdbmi = GdbController()
    response = gdbmi.write('b main')
    response = gdbmi.write('target remote localhost:2331')
    response = gdbmi.write('mon reset 0')
    response = gdbmi.write('c')
```

[gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui) provides a much cooler example.

Comment: Current pygdbmi home page: https://cs01.github.io/pygdbmi/