# How to script gdb (with python)? Example add breakpoints, run, what breakpoint did we hit?

Tags: unit-testing, scripting, gdb, openocd, gdb-python

I'm trying to create a little unit test with gdb, 
for a embedded mcu that is controlled by [OpenOCD](http://openocd.berlios.de/web/) (that gives me control over my target via a gdb server).

So I would like to automate this with some scripting of gdb.

I would like to write some kind of script for gdb that more or less does this:

1. Add a couple of breakpoints
2. Start the program
3. When we stop, where did it stop (get the frame info)
4. Quit.

Any ideas?

A example on how to do this in python gdb scripting would be nice.

Thanks
Johan

---

*Note*:

Let's say that we have this basic structure, 
that more or less goes into test_failed() or test_success()
depending on what the function start_test() returns.

```
void test_failed() {    
    while(1);    
}

void test_success() {    
    while(1);    
}

int main(void) {    
    int status = start_test();    

    if( status > 0 ) {    
        test_failed();    
    }    
    test_success();

    while(1);    
}
```

To do this manually in gdb is very strait forward,

```
(gdb) break test_success
Breakpoint 1 at 0x20: file src/main.c, line 9.
(gdb) break test_failed
Breakpoint 2 at 0x18: file src/main.c, line 5.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, test_success () at src/main.c:9
9       while(1);
(gdb) frame
#0  test_success () at src/main.c:9
9       while(1);
(gdb)
```

So the next step I tried was to add those gdb commands into a gdb startup script that more or less just looked like this.

```
break test_success
break test_failed
target remote localhost:3333
cont 
frame
```

and start it with

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --batch --command=commands.gdb main.elf
```

And this kind of works, but it is not very nice.
How do I do this with the "new and cool" python scripts, 
that gdb seem to support.

Comment: Also check the tutorial on the wiki: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PythonGdbTutorial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FYI recent gdb versions are scriptable in Python. You can call python code from the gdb command line. This opens a whole new world, check the relevant documentation. From the command line run:

```
 dnf/yum/apt-get install gdb-doc
 info gdb extending python
```

If you do not like the text-based info browser, here is one (among many?) alternative, graphical browser:

```
yelp 'info:gdb' # , go to "Extending"
```

Here is a sample gdb-python script. It attaches gdb to the first "your_program" found running.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import string

def backquotes(cmdwords):
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmdwords, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return output.strip()

pid = backquotes(['pgrep', 'your_program'])

gdb.execute("attach " + str(pid))
```

Comment: You don't happen to have some nice links? or a howto or something that can push me into the right direction (since the old gdb scripting style is not very optimal...)

Answer (score 12):

A reduced example that I'm currently using:

```py
class DebugPrintingBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    debugging_IDs = frozenset({37, 153, 420})
    def stop(self):
        top = gdb.newest_frame()
        someVector = top.read_var('aVectorVar')
        # Access the begin() & end() pointer of std::vector in GNU Standard C++ lib
        first = someVector['_M_impl']['_M_start']
        last = someVector['_M_impl']['_M_finish']
        values = []
        while first != last:
            values.append(int(first.dereference()['intID']))
            first = first + 1
        if not set(values) & debugging_IDs:
            return False # skip: none of the items we're looking for can be found by ID in the vector on the stack
        print("Found other accompanying IDs: {}".format(values))
        return True # drop to gdb's prompt
# Ensure shared libraries are loaded already
gdb.execute("start")
# Set our breakpoint, which happens to reside in some shared lib, hence the "start" previously
DebugPrintingBreakpoint("source.cpp:42")
gdb.execute("continue")
```

You can execute this script from gdb's prompt like this:

```
(gdb) source script.py
```

Or from the command-line:

```
$ gdb --command script.py ./executable.elf
```

See the complete [GDB Python API docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html) for further info.

Comment: I don't have `gdb.continue` on 7.7.1, what version are you?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 I think that's a typo I made. It should probably be: gdb.execute("continue") ? Can you confirm that works (I don't have immediate access to the test setup I used that ^^ script on)?

Comment: I can point gdb to my python file with --command <the path.py> but how do I specify arguments to my python program (i.e. the script uses sys.argv)?

Comment: @nmz787 I don't think GDB's Python support passes command line arguments at all. You can probably use environment variables instead for passing arguments. Then do `env OPT_X=y gdb --command script.py ./executable.elf`

Comment: Hmm, your comment doesn't make sense to me... and I think it is because I was trying to debug my Python script using GDB (step through the Python code, not the interpreter's assembly), rather than control GDB via Python. When I use the --command <path to my py file> I do see the usage instructions my python code produces with no cmd-line args... so I thought I was close to stepping through Python code lines. Maybe you know a tutorial for debugging Python code using GDB (I want to use reverse debugging, something the Python IDE debuggers don't support). I haven't found a good tutorial...

Comment: No, for Python itself I usually only use post-mortem debugging (i.e. analyzing tracebacks) or debug-prints. Which I agree is less than ideal

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the answer while asking the question... and it and it was a really simple thing.

You should not use both the "--command" and the "--eval" at the same time if you expect them to be executed in a specific order!

A more predicable way is to put everything in the commands.gdb file and ignore --eval.

So it becomes something like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --batch --command=commands.gdb main.elf
```

Where commands.gdb looks like this:

```
break test_success
break test_failed
target remote localhost:3333
cont 
frame
```

But it would probably be so much nicer to do this with something like python instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to note something that I find confusing whenever I come back to this topic (Note, I'm currently on Ubuntu 14.04, GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1):

First, there are references about it being "*possible to invoke `gdb` as an interpreter*":

- [9. Scripting gdb — The Cliffs of Inanity (http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548)](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548)
- http://blog.scottt.tw/2012/01/exploring-gdb-python-api-with-ipython_31.html

... meaning, one would write a script text file with the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/gbd -P` or `#!/usr/bin/gbd --python`, then write Python code in it, then make it executable `chmod +x pygdbscript`, then run `./pygdbscript`; ... but as in this post:

- [GDB - Missing "--python" Parameter? / Newbie Corner / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178891)

..., I get `gdb: unrecognized option '--python'` if I try anything like that. Apparently this option is/was a feature in some "archer" branch of `gdb`?!

---

So, in order to run a Python script in `gdb`, there are actually two ways:

- Name your script file with extension `.py`; say `test.py` here:

```py
def Something():
  print("hello from python")

Something()
gdb.execute("quit");
```

Note, in this case, you just write plain Python code; and you do not need to `import gdb` in order to access the `gdb` object. This you can run with either of:

```sh
gdb -x test.py
gdb -x=test.py
gdb --command test.py
gdb --command=test.py
gdb -command test.py
gdb -command=test.py
```

... which seem to be equivalent, as the result for any of these is the same printout, before `gdb` is instructed to exit by the script:

```
$ gdb -x=test.py
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
...
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
hello from python
```

**NOTE** that for this case, also names like `test.gdb.py` will be interpreted as pure Python scripts, since then end in `.py`.

- Name your script *anything else* - as long as it *does **not*** end with `.py` extension; say `test.pygdb` here:

```
python
def Something():
  print("hello from python")

Something()
gdb.execute("quit");
end
```

In this case, `gdb` interprets the script as being a `gdb` script, i.e. with `gdb` commands - and that means, that whatever Python code you may want to write in here, **must** be wrapped in "`python`" as a starting line and "`end`" at end of the Python code. Again, it would be called with any of these equivalent calls:

```sh
gdb -x test.pygdb
gdb -x=test.pygdb
gdb --command test.pygdb
gdb --command=test.pygdb
gdb -command test.pygdb
gdb -command=test.pygdb
```

... and then the output is the same as in the previous case (since it is the same Python script running):

```
$ gdb -x test.pygdb 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
...
hello from python
```

---

And in response to OP: if the C code in OP is in `/tmp/myprog.c` - with an added `int start_test() { return rand() % 50; }` on top, otherwise it won't compile - , and is compiled with with `gcc -g myprog.c -o myprog.exe` into `/tmp/myprog.exe`; then you can use a **`myprog.gdb.py`** script like this:

```py
# need to specify the executable file which we debug (in this case, not from command line)
# here `gdb` command `file` is used - it does not have a Python equivalent (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Objfiles-In-Python.html#index-Objfile_002eframe_005ffilters)
# so we must use gdb.execute:

myexefile="/tmp/myprog.exe"
print("""
### myprog.gdb.py is running: """ + myexefile + """ - and adding breakpoints:
""")

gdb.execute("file " + myexefile)
gdb.execute("set pagination off")

ax = gdb.Breakpoint("test_success")
bx = gdb.Breakpoint("test_failed")

gdb.execute("run")

# here the program will break, so we can do:

print("""
### myprog.gdb.py after the break - current stack frame:
""")

current_frame_at_break = gdb.selected_frame()
print(current_frame_at_break) # instead of gdb.execute("frame")

print("""
### myprog.gdb.py - backtrace:
""")

gdb.execute("backtrace 2")

print("""
### myprog.gdb.py - go to frame that called current frame:
""")

parent_frame = current_frame_at_break.older()
print(parent_frame)
status_var = parent_frame.read_var("status")
print("status_var is: ", status_var)
```

... then run this script with:

```
$ gdb -x myprog.gdb.py
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
....
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".

### myprog.gdb.py is running: /tmp/myprog.exe - and adding breakpoints:

Breakpoint 1 at 0x400565: file myprog.c, line 8.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40055f: file myprog.c, line 4.

Breakpoint 2, test_failed () at myprog.c:4
4       while(1);    

### myprog.gdb.py after the break - current stack frame:

{stack=0x7fffffffdc70,code=0x40055b,!special}

### myprog.gdb.py - backtrace:

#0  test_failed () at myprog.c:4
#1  0x000000000040058c in main () at myprog.c:15

### myprog.gdb.py - go to frame that called current frame:

{stack=0x7fffffffdc90,code=0x400567,!special}
status_var is: 33
(gdb)
```

Note that at the end of this script, the `(gdb)` interactive prompt remains, and you can use it normally here; if you don't need the interactive prompt, you can do `gdb.execute("quit");` as in the above scripts to force `gdb` to exit instead at end of script execution.

Also, for an example of subclassing breakpoint class in gdb Python, see [How to print the current line of source at breakpoint in GDB and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893554/how-to-print-the-current-line-of-source-at-breakpoint-in-gdb-and-nothing-else/17894703#17894703)

Comment: How to pass arguments to the python script, e.g., the name of the executable?