# gdb - pipe output of internal command to the shell command

Tags: gdb

Is there any way how to pipe output of internal gdb command to some shell command like `grep` - the variant of `[cmd] ! grep` in `mdb`?

To be more clear: in solaris `mdb` you can e.g. write

```
main::dis ! grep call
```

to detect which functions are called from the main (or grep some register names to see how it is changed). I am interested if there is such possibility to do so just in gdb without necessarity to switching from gdb.

Comment: Maybe it's time to start looking into Python scripting to define new commands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060565/how-to-script-gdb-with-python-example-add-breakpoints-run-what-breakpoint-d :-)

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456294/gdb-in-one-command

Comment: For example, `gdb -p 1234 -batch -ex 'bt'` prints a backtrace for process 1234.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new GDB command has been introduced, namely `pipe`. If you want to process the output of a GDB command using some shell command or some script, that can be done using this new command.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Shell-Commands.html

```
pipe [command] | shell_command
```

Comment: Thanks for info, it is exactly what I was missing. Hope it will be part of official release soon.

Comment: @Michy, it's part of official releases for some years - maybe you thus want to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Seven years later, I still have not found a native way to do this, so I wrote the [`shell-pipe`](https://github.com/hq6/GdbShellPipe) gdb extension. Its complete source code is replicated here for completeness.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import gdb
import string
import subprocess
import sys


class ShellPipe (gdb.Command):
    "Command to pipe gdb internal command output to external commands."

    def __init__(self):
        super (ShellPipe, self).__init__("shell-pipe",
                gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                gdb.COMPLETE_NONE, True)
        gdb.execute("alias -a sp = shell-pipe", True)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        arg = arg.strip()
        if arg == "":
            print("Argument required (gdb_command_and_args | externalcommand..).")
            return

        gdb_command, shell_commands = None, None

        if '|' in arg:
            gdb_command, shell_commands = arg.split("|", maxsplit=1)
            gdb_command, shell_commands = gdb_command.strip(), shell_commands.strip()
        else:
            gdb_command = arg

        # Collect the output and feed it through the pipe
        output = gdb.execute(gdb_command, True, True)
        if shell_commands:
            shell_process = subprocess.Popen(shell_commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            shell_process.communicate(output.encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(output)

ShellPipe()
```

After sourcing `ShellPipeCommand.py` in `$HOME/.gdbinit`, one can now pipe internal gdb commands to external shell commands.

```
    (gdb) shell-pipe disas | grep main
    0x0000000000400527 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
    0x000000000040052e <+8>:     movq   $0x4005e4,-0x8(%rbp)
 => 0x0000000000400536 <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
    0x000000000040053a <+20>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
```

Comment: I enhanced your script a little to allow output redirection with > as well. This works in linux at least. After the `if '|' in arg:` I added an `elif '>' in arg:` and prepended `cat > ` to the `shell_commands` variable.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly. If you want to a log results of your GDB commands that you ran during a debug session, then Yes there is support for this from GDB.

```
show logging                    # displays weather logging is on / off
set logging on                  # enable logging
set logging off                 # disable logging
set logging file log-file.txt   # set name for log file, default is gdb.txt
```

the log file will be generated in your current directory.

Further you can append logs of debug sessions or create new on every debug session using

```
set logging overwrite <on/off>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The logging is not exactly what I am searching for. In the Solaris mdb there is a possibility to write e.g. 'main::dis ! grep call' and the debugger will call grep on the disasembly result. I am searching for the similar way to do so in the gdb - run grep of dissasemble command output (or send it to the less). I could use e.g. objdump and grep its result or get the output from the logging file you mentioned, but I am interested if there is way to do it just inside the gdb.

Comment: don't forget to set pagination off.... logging/shell command is currently the only way to do it e.g. set logging on, disas main, set logging off, shell grep call gdb.txt, someone is working on a pipe command, which should may make this more straight forward