# Executing commands at breakpoint in gdb via python interface

Tags: python, gdb

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935443), as I'm working through the python interface to gdb.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431341) is similar but does not have an answer.

I'm extending a gdb.breakpoint in python so that it writes certain registers to file, and then jumps to an address: at `0x4021ee`, I want to write stuff to file, then jump to `0x4021f3`

However, nothing in `command` is ever getting executed.

```
import gdb
class DebugPrintingBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__(self, spec, command):
        super(DebugPrintingBreakpoint, self).__init__(spec, gdb.BP_BREAKPOINT, internal = False)
        self.command = command

    def stop(self):
        with open('tracer', 'a') as f:
            f.write(chr(gdb.parse_and_eval("$rbx") ^ 0x71))
            f.close()
        return False



gdb.execute("start")
DebugPrintingBreakpoint("*0x4021ee", "jump *0x4021f3")
gdb.execute("continue")
```

If I explicitly add `gdb.execute(self.command)` to the end of `stop()`, I get `Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> Cannot execute this command while the selected thread is running.:`

Anyone have a working example of command lists with breakpoints in python gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options to try:

1. Use [gdb.post_event](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html) from stop() to run the desired command later. I believe you'll need to return True from your function then call continue from your event.
2. Create a normal breakpoint and listen to [events.stop](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html) to check if your breakpoint was hit.

Answer (score 1):

The `Breakpoint.stop` method is called when, in gdb terms, the inferior is still "executing".  Partly this is a bookkeeping oddity -- of course the inferior isn't really executing, it is stopped while gdb does a bit of breakpoint-related processing.  Internally it is more like gdb hasn't yet decided to report the stop to other interested parties inside gdb.  This funny state is what lets `stop` work so nicely vis a vis `next` and other execution commands.

Some commands in gdb can't be invoked while the inferior is running, like `jump`, as you've found.

One thing you could try -- I have never tried this and don't know if it would work -- would be to assign to the PC in your `stop` method.  This might do the right thing; but of course you should know that the documentation warns against doing weird stuff like this.

Failing that I think the only approach is to fall back to using `commands` to attach the `jump` to the breakpoint.  This has the drawback that it will interfere with `next`.

One final way would be to patch the running code to insert a jump or just a sequence of `nop`s.