# How can i invoke gdb using python to run a module

Tags: python, gdb

I have a requirement to run a 'C'-module in gdb but this gdb should be involked by python script.

Comment: the `subprocess` module, which according to [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/] is to replace the os.system call (among other things)

Comment: W_P are there any existing commands in gdb enabled python.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

```
subprocess.Popen(['gdb', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc'])
```

If you are using Python 2.x and you only want to record the output, you can use [commands](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html), but it is deprecated since 2.6.
You might want to check [Invoke and control GDB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482869/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-python)

Comment: I think this is the only way for this.
And thanks for reply.

Comment: Can you give some sample python scripts to control gdb

Comment: You can check this: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548

Comment: Are you familear with this python enaled with gdb.  If so how to import gdb in python.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I never used gdb with Python

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution as always: [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).

`os.system("gdb arg1 arg2 etc")`

Comment: Apart from this are there any commands to do this.

Comment: the `subprocess` module makes this inappropriate for the majority of use cases.