# Do any one have gdb.py file or its link

Tags: python, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import 'GDB' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792483/how-to-import-gdb-in-python)

To import gdb in my python code i need gdb.py, 
but i am unable to get it.
so please if any one has it can you give its
link.