# How to access gdb from python

Tags: python, linux, gdb

I am looking for a way to access results from gdb from python. I need to debug a c program using gdb and access the results from python. It is like calling gdb from python to debug c program.

Answer (score 0):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call `gdb` on the compiled binary (e.g. `a.out`):

```
import subprocess

# if you have arguments to gdb, you can supply then in the list itself.
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gdb', 'a.out'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
proc.communicate('\tGDB Output:\n')
```

Reference:

http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should invert the problem and instead add support what you need by extending gdb: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html.  When python runs within gdb it has access to gdb API.  See [How to import 'GDB' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792483/how-to-import-gdb-in-python) for some extra details.