# python script to dump ELF (core and out)?

Tags: python, elf, coredump

I am looking for a python script that can dump ELF file (of type core-dump).

Any pointers to existing scripts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use GDB to look at the core dump file.  You can control GDB from Python:

[Invoke and control GDB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482869/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-python)

But recent versions of GDB have Python built in!  You might be able to to what you want from within GDB, rather than running GDB from within Python.

http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PythonGdb

P.S. You would probably be interested in the book *Gray Hat Python*:

http://nostarch.com/ghpython.htm