# invoke and control gdb from ruby

Tags: python, ruby, gdb

is there any support for ruby to invoke and control gdb. I need gdb control from ruby to send gdb commands for c/c++ debugging sessions.  i need the tool mentioned in the question  given the link below for ruby

[Invoke and control GDB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482869/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-python)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact programmatically with gdb is to simply use gdb's Python layer to do things.  Then you can communicate with it any way that is convenient -- say, by sending JSON messages to it, and having your Python code in gdb respond.

However, the more classic way is to use gdb's MI ("Machine Interface"), which is a mode gdb provides where its output is structured in a way that is more readily parsed.

Googling for "ruby gdb MI" shows some plausible libraries, like [this one](https://github.com/mcarpenter/rubug), or [this one](https://github.com/eqv/gdb-mi-parser).

Comment: thanks Tom for your answer. i have seen those libraries but i am not sure to continue with them. it seems the best way is  to communicate with python and ruby as you noticed. Since python gdb have large capacity and great capabilities. i could'not find alternative for ruby in that scope.